# Manually installing a software library in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I want to install an open-source code(REEF3D) in ubuntu 18.04. To increase the computational efficiency during running the code, I have to install HYPRE( high performance preconditions) which will help parallel iteration solution. HYPRE requires MPI to be installed first. So I installed openmpi and went well. I downloaded hypre-2.11.2.2.tar.gz (latest version), copy to the home directory, unzipped it there and navigated to the directory src within hypre-2.11.2. (I followed this from the manual of the code.) However, when I tried to configure using the command line  ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/hypre, I got the following message:

---

checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for mpxlc... no
checking for mpixlc... no
checking for mpiicc... no
checking for mpicc... mpicc
checking for mpxlC... no
checking for mpixlcxx... no
checking for mpiicpc... no
checking for mpiCC... mpiCC
checking for mpxlf... no
checking for mpixlf77... no
checking for mpiifort... no
checking for mpif77... mpif77
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether mpicc accepts -g... yes
checking for mpicc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether mpiCC accepts -g... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... yes
checking whether mpif77 accepts -g... yes
checking how to get verbose linking output from mpif77... -v

---

Note that I have already installed gcc, g++ and gfortran compilers.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well it doesn't look like there is issue? You usually get a similar printout when you are trying to configure. Can you include the issue for people to see? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and format the question as well.

Comment: I also recommend https://askubuntu.com/ since this is Ubuntu related.